# CNTK on Data Science VM (FasterRCNN): ImportError: No module called 'utils.rpn'

Tags: python, azure, cntk, azure-dsvm

I have just set up a new Data Science Virtual Machine on Azure. I wanted to run a script FasterRCNN.py from
https://github.com/karolzak/CNTK-Hotel-pictures-classificator
but received an error:

> from utils.rpn.rpn_helpers import create_rpn, create_proposal_target_layer
>
> ImportError: No module named 'utils.rpn'

The environment I am running the script on has Python 3.4 and CNTK 2.1 installed.

I tried to add a *Detection* or *Detection/utils* directories (by editing *~./bashrc*) to PYTHONPATH:

> export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/home/username/CNTK-Hotel-pictures-classificator/Detection"

as described in
https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/2705
but the error persists.

Update:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kq8CJ.png)

Comment: Are you sure this is Python 3.4? The DSVM comes with Python 2.7 and 3.5. I would recommend you use the 3.5 environment. If you need a 3.4 environment, you will see at the bottom of the GitHub issue you linked to that you need to rename the binary files.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have been testing on both Python 3.4 and Python 3.5, see screenshot below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kq8CJ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is struggling:
the solution to that problem is creating an empty `__init__.py` file in `utils` directory.

Comment: I just came back to see if I could help. Glad you found a solution.